# Mongoose Populate not returning related data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following Models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const imputerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dninie: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  second_lastname: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  phone : {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  qr: {
    type : String,
    unique: true,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Imputer', imputerSchema)

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const imputationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  qr: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Imputer',
  },
  imputation_date: {
    type: String,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true,
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number, Number],
    index: '2d',
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Imputation', imputationSchema);
```

and I trying to make a query like this:

```
Imputation.find()
        .populate('imputer.qr')
        .exec()
        .then(docs => console.log(docs));
```

I also try

```
   Imputation.find()
            .populate('imputer')
            .exec()
            .then(docs => console.log(docs));
```

But I'm only got the documents on the imputation model without the field on the imputers model.

Here are some screenshots of how the documents look[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `imputationSchema` as follows:

```
const imputationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  qr: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Imputer",
    trim: true,
    required: true,
   },
// other fields...
});
```

and then query like this:

```
Imputation.find()
            .populate('qr')
            .exec()
            .then(docs => console.log(docs));
```